# How to use `ng2-select` in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I tried to use this [library](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/).

I have created one componnt like in example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-select',
  properties: [
    'allowClear',
    'placeholder',
    'items',
    'multiple',
    'showSearchInputInDropdown']
})
```

Why this component witout export class?

I tried to use `single-demo` demo.

**Error is:**

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

Comment: Can someone share an example?

Comment: I see you're using this control with angular form. Can you post code of how this control looks on your template? Are you using ngModel, formControlName?

Comment: Seems you should just add `name` to your control `<ng-select name="mySelect" [(ngModel)]="value`

Comment: Can you help reproduce this?